# Wordpress: Conflicting Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In my woocommerce plugin im getting an error to where my filter by price or category dropdown sidebar widget do not respond. Im sure to what exactly what is conflicting within my site.

[--- SUBJECT SITE ---](http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/product-category/shop/)

Im getting two errors when i test with firebug:

TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function in jquery...r=3.6.1 (line 13)

TypeError: product_cat_dropdown is null

Java where c.curCSS does not work:

```
 if(b==="absolute"||b==="relative"||b==="fixed"){b=parseInt(a.css("zIndex"),10);if(!isNaN(b)&&b!==0)return b}a=a.parent()}}return 0},disableSelection:function(){return this.bind((c.support.selectstart?"selectstart":"mousedown")+".ui-disableSelection",function(a){a.preventDefault()})},enableSelection:function(){return this.unbind(".ui-disableSelection")}});c.each(["Width","Height"],function(a,b){function d(f,g,l,m){c.each(e,function(){g-=parseFloat(c.curCSS(f,"padding"+this,true))||0;if(l)g-=parseFloat(c.curCSS(f, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running this:

```
var product_cat_dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown_product_cat");
```

But that element doesn't exist on the page.